# Select option entries are only shown on the first select attempt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using **vuetify** and an I'm trying to **populate a select box**...

...using this **JSON** Object:

```
[
    {
        "configurator": {
            "group": {
                "property": [
                    {
                        "id": "STATUS",
                        "value": [
                            {
                                "id": "OK",
                                "text": "OK"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "NOK",
                                "text": "not OK",
                                "selected": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

...and I'm trying to render this component:

```
<v-list v-for="(item, i) in jsonObjPruef.configurator.group.property" :key="i">
  <v-select
    v-model="item.value"
    :items="item.value"
    :label="item.text"
  />
</v-list>
```

Page loads without warnings and errors and I can select from the expected values ("OK", "not OK").

While choosing e.g. "OK" the following warning is displayed:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got String with value "OK".
```

And now if **I'm trying to select again I only can pick the value I chose before** ("OK").

**The select option entries are only shown on the first select attempt.**

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** `v-model` means: *"where user selection is saved"*. If you save it over the same exact property which holds your options, the options are gone and the `<v-select>` is broken.

---

`v-model` replaces `jsonObjPruef.configurator.group.property` with the selected option, when you select it. Which makes the `<v-select>` no longer have `items`.

You should specify a different `v-model` - a model property in which you store the selection, (i.e: `results`):

```html
<v-list v-for="(item, i) in jsonObjPruef.configurator.group.property" :key="i">
  <v-select
    v-model="results[i]"
    :items="item.value"
    :label="item.text"
  />
</v-list>
```

In `data`, you need to initialize `results : {}`.

Now `results` will hold the selected results and you can place a watcher on it to trigger additional functionality when it changes. It doesn't have to be an object, it could be an array. It depends on what you currently have.
Obviously, you can rename `results` to something less generic, which makes more sense in your specific example.

If you need more help, please add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).